# HTML DOM Drag and Drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, dom

Yes, this may sound like a frequent question, but Google nor stackoverflow are giving me the answer that I want. I did stumble upon a few results on the WWW, but only found HUGE scripts for just this 1 piece of functionality.

The thing is, I remember doing this before, but I don't exactly remember how. I did it within ONE function and by adding event listeners and stuff along those lines.

Basically, I need a pure DOM script to drag and drop HTML elements for a throwback to older web browsers that don't support the new HTML5 standards. Must be down with the even 'onmousedown', and the text/image must be held for at least 1.5 seconds before calling the dragging.

Thoughts and ideas? Help would be greatly appreciated, guys.

I'm also a bit rusty with screen coordinates and stuff. With this code I want the text to follow the cursor EXACTLY. Not be like, 5 pixels "off" if you know what I mean.

What I had before (parameter of moveText is supposed to be an HTMLDivElement and it's innerText):

```
function moveText(t){
            var id=t.id;
            var interval=setInterval(function(){
                increment=increment+1;
                if(increment>=3){
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    t.addEventListener("mousemove",function(event){
                        t.style.position="absolute";
                        t.style.top=event.screenY+"px";
                        t.style.left=event.screenX+"px";
                    });
                }
            },500);
            t.addEventListener("mouseup",function(){
                increment=0;
                clearInterval(interval);
            });

        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you post code in your question it will help us understand what you're trying to do.